# How to generate unique IDs for UI components of Vaadin applications?

Tags: java, css, selenium, automated-tests, vaadin

Normally a Vaadin application sets a sequential ID for each user interface component of the application. Unfortunately these IDs are not very useful for the purpose of test automation as they are generated dynamically and may change during runtime (per session or when new components are added etc.).

For test automation one need (at least per application) unique and static ID for each component.

A) Can Vaadin's `setId()` method [1] be utilized to generate test automation friendly component IDs?

B) Can Vaadin's `addStyleName()` or `setStyleName()` be useful by generating a custom CSS style which later could be "abused" as an ID?

Some design ideas as discussed in [3]:

- separate id creation from id assignment
- use a naming strategy to create the id
- assign the id at component attach time

---

[1] https://vaadin.com/api/7.7.3/com/vaadin/ui/Component.html#setId-java.lang.String-

[2] https://vaadin.com/api/7.7.3/com/vaadin/ui/Component.html#setStyleName-java.lang.String-

[3] https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/278068

Answer (score 1):

> A) Can Vaadin's setId() method [1] be utilized to generate test automation friendly component IDs?

Yes, it replaced the deprecated `setDebugId()`. From its javadoc:

> Description copied from interface: com.vaadin.ui.Component
>
> Adds an unique id for component that is used in the client-side for testing
>   purposes. Keeping identifiers unique is the responsibility of the
>   programmer.

We did not use it with any kind of *naming strategy automation "framework"* as it's discussed in your 3rd link. We manually set component IDs according to an internal agreement. Please be aware that not all *components* can be assigned IDs, eg [menu items](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-menubar.html#components.menubar.menuitem).

---

> B) Can Vaadin's addStyleName() or setStyleName() be useful by generating a custom CSS style which later could be "abused" as an ID?

You could, but it's more or less the same with A). You can then find elements using `findElement(By.className("some-class"))`;

> public static By className(@NotNull String className)
>
> Finds elements based on the value of the "class" attribute. If an element has many
>   classes then this will match against each of them. For example if the
>   value is "one two onone", then the following "className"s will match:
>   "one" and "two"

---

Another option would be using xpath, eg `findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'column-hiding-toggle')]/span/div[text()='Name']"))`.

Although very powerful and flexible (if I'm not mistaking both `By.id` & `By.className` are implemented with xpaths underneath the hood), its downside is that it can become *high maintenance* if the structure of your user interfaces changes frequently.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'm aware of xpath and already use it extensively. My question aims mainly at things that can be done on Vaadin's site in sense of generating static IDs to make usage of xpath and/or css selectors (Selenium) easier and better maintainable. Cause as you already mentioned maintenance can become a problem if the UI changes even if one uses intelligent xpaths.A clear naming or ID strategy would have two big advantages: 1. defining selectors would be much easier and faster and 2. the defined selectors would be more robust thus would require less maintenance effort.

Comment: The aim is on the one side to make test automation development and maintenance more efficient and on the other side to provide developers with more reliable tests.